# System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs

Tags: vb.net

i want to send button click event to textbox keypressevent. what to do??

my code is

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, _ 
       ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    MessageBox.Show "Hai"
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   TextBox1_KeyPress(Sender,e)

End Sub
```

Error Comes from e

*System.EventArgs and KeyPressEventArgs*

Comment: The code is nonsense, clicking a button just isn't the same thing as pressing a key.  Hard to guess the intention, SendKeys.Send() maybe.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is always a bad approach to call an event handler directly in that way.

In my opinion you should refactor your code and extract from the KeyPress event the code that you want to call from Button_Click and call it directly

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, _ 
       ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    CommonCode()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    CommonCode()
End Sub


Private Sub CommonCode()
    MessageBox.Show "Hai"
End Sub
```

However, your error lies in the fact that `TextBox1_KeyPress` expects a `KeyPressEventArgs` not the simple `EventArgs` received in the Button1_Click. You could bypass this creating a new instance of `KeyPressEventArgs` and passing it to the `TextBox1_KeyPress`, but, as I have said, this is a bad practice. Don't even think that Windows or the Framework will handle in some meaningful way a call to an event that doesn't originate from its internal code.

**EDIT:** Just to show how to pass an instance of KeyEventArgs. Again I don't reccomend this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim x = new KeyPressEventArgs("A"c)
    CommonCode(e, x)
End Sub

Private Sub CommonCode(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e KeyPressEventArgs)

    MessageBox.Show "KeyPressed = " + e.KeyChar.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: hai steve thanks for the reply. actualy i want 2 prameters in the commoncode sub. the parameters are (ByVal sender As Object, _ 
       ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) so what i do???

Comment: You pass it to the CommonCode sub. But to answer correctly I ask you: What are you really doing in the CommonCode sub?

Comment: how can i pass it to the CommonCode. Is it Right CommonCode(TextBox1, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)

Comment: answer updated, look at the edit

Comment: sir its not working. i use vb.net. the code Dim x = new KeyPressEventArgs() is not supported

Comment: Yes, sorry my fault. The constructor for KeyPressEventArgs requires the char as parameter.